# why is my jquery code not being executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Going slightly insane here, I'm wondering why a simple

```
console.log("test")
```

isn't appearing in my console. My code is below. I also tried

```
$(function() {
   console.log("test")
});
```

but that didn't do it either. Isn't the purpose of the above and my function below to wait until the page loads and then do the function? No matter where I put the  code - header, body...it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Autocomplete</title>
    <meta content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" name="viewport" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2.js"></script>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="mainPage">

        <div data-role="content">

            <p>
                In this example autoComplete uses a local array comprised of strings. This also shows an example of the matchFromStart property set to false.
            </p>


            <p>
                <input type="text" id="searchField" placeholder="Categories">
                <ul id="suggestions" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
            </p>

        </div>

    </div>

    <script>


    $(document).on("pageshow", "mainPage", function() {
   console.log("test")
});

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need a `#` before `mainPage` in your jQuery event.

Comment: $(document).on("pageshow", "#mainPage", function() {
   console.log("test")
}); made no difference.And any idea why $(function() {
   console.log("test")
}); doesn't work?

Comment: Well, what errors are you getting in the console then?

Comment: @null I'm not getting any error in console. I'm talking about the Console in Chrome, to be clear - 'Inspect Element', on the menu.

Answer (score 1):

The console is ready way before the page so you won't get anything by using document.ready callback. Chances are something has overridden your console. To find out if that's true, inspect your console object by simply typing `console` into your console. In Chrome, it should return something like this:

```
Console {memory: MemoryInfo, debug: function, error: function, info: function, log: function…}
```

If that proves true, you need to find where in your code is the console redefined. Also, you might want to test your code in another browser - perhaps you have an extension or something that's blocking the console for some reason.

But before everything, please double-check your code for syntax errors.

Also, make sure you've set your console to show logs (the filter button, it's next to the clear console button).

Comment: Thanks for that, when I type console into Chrome console though and hit enter I get nothing. And any idea why $(function() {
   console.log("test")
}); wouldn't work - I mean just to eliminate the whole document.ready possibility. As for syntax errors, I've checked it to the best of my knowledge and I think they'd come up in console in any case - errors are coming up, just not what I want to print to console!

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, that's weird, check your filters, I just remembered you could be actually hiding all that info on "accidental purpose" :) Also, please let me know if you have any unusual extensions. And try a different browser, or at least an incognito session in Chrome.

Comment: Will do - not just yet as have to go, but will do it later. Thanks.

Comment: I get the 'test' appearing in other browsers, just not the one on my current machine. Will investigate further and let you know...

Comment: Probably an extension then. At least now you know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was to do with my console settings. In console there's some grey buttons along the bottom - All, Errors, Warnings, Logs, Debug. Well, Errors was selected, for some reason. So I was getting nothing in Console but errors. Click 'All' and it works properly.

Having said that, my code was also missing that # before mainpage, as highlighted by null.